# How to print only if specific time starts with x in Python

Tags: python

Hi I'm a newbie learning python and I want to print something only if current time starts with x (for example, if current time starts with = 4, print "hi", time = 4:18), this is the code I made, it says attribute error:

```py
import datetime

local = datetime.datetime.now().time().replace(microsecond=0)


if local.startswith('16'):
    print("Hi! It's ", local)
```

Comment: You're trying to call a `str` method on a `datetime` object which doesn't work. You can either convert to string, or check the hour value

Comment: It's also helpful when posting on StackOverflow to copy-paste the entire error message so we can see exactly what went wrong. Good job on giving a small code example to reproduce the error; that makes it much easier to answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.replace()` method returns a `date` object. `date` objects don't have a `.startswith()` method. That method is only for `str`.

Try converting your date to a string first:

```py
if str(local).startswith('16'):
    print("Hi! It's ", local)
```

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) lists all of the methods available on a `date` object.

Comment: Better yet, don't convert, just check the hour.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert it to a `string`, as `datetime` objects have no `startswith()` method. Use `strftime`, example:

```py
import datetime
t = datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 23, 0, 0)
t2 = t.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

will yield:

`'02/23/2012'`. Once it's converted, you can use `t2.startswith()`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hour of the time and check if it is 16:

```py
if local.hour == 16:
   print("Hi! It's ",local)
```

If you need to use `startswith()` then you can convert it to a string like this:

```py
if str(local).startswith('16'):
    print("Hi! It's ", local)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not a good way. Check the time as int is the better solution here.
replace() has 2 needed str arguments. You use a named attribute which doesn't exist.

Comment: You're thinking of the string replace method, this is the datetime replace method